# Linq to get distinct property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data table that looks like this (Not my table can't change the data)

```
Code     Version    Description
AAA      0.0.0.0    Test of AAA
AAA      0.0.0.1    Test of AAA
BBB      0.0.0.0    Test of BBB
CCC      0.0.0.0    Test of CCC
CCC      0.0.0.1    Test of CCC
```

I want to return a list of unique "Code" values only.

So my desired result will be:

```
AAA   Test of AAA
BBB   Test of BBB
CCC   Test of CCC
```

I've created a comparer class:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MY_DATA_TABLE>
{
    public bool Equals(MY_DATA_TABLE x, MY_DATA_TABLE y)
    {
        return x.CODE == y.CODE;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MY_DATA_TABLE obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and in my code I have:

```
var mapCodes = (from mtc in GetAllData() select mtc)
                    .Distinct(new MyComparer ())
                    .ToList();
```

However it is still returning the entire contents back.

How can I achieve getting a distinct list by property?

Comment: Unlikley to be your problem, but your implementation of GetHashCode is incorrect. HashCodes should match if the objects are "equal" so you want `obj.Code.GetHashCode()`

Comment: *How can I achieve getting a distinct list by property?* By **correctly** implementing `GetHashCode`.

Comment: you probably want DistinctBy extension from MoreLinq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your `GetHashCode()` function:

```
public int GetHashCode(MY_DATA_TABLE obj)
{
    return obj.CODE.GetHashCode();
}
```

Rule is, that both Equals and `GetHashCode()` should check the same properties, and you checking just Code in `Equals()` and whiole object in `GetHashCode()`

Comment: That was it.  I didn't realize I wasn't checking the property.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to do a group by and take the first value in each group if `Version` doesn't matter.

```
var mapCodes = (from mtc in GetAllData()
                group mtc by mtc.Code into grp
                select grp.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer of course

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MoreLinq's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) DistinctBy

```
 var mapCodes = (from mtc in GetAllData()
                 select mtc).DistinctBy(x=>x.Code).ToList();
```

Or just:

```
var mapCodes = GetAllData().DistinctBy(x=>x.Code).ToList();
```

Or you can correct the GetHashCode method as mentioned in the comments